# Annotating rows if backwards relationship exists (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have 3 tables: `Recommendation`, `Article` and `User`.

Recommendation has 4 columns:

```
id | integer
article_id |integer
user_id |integer
submit_time |integer
```

Article has 3 columns:

```
id | integer
title
url
```

I need to obtain a list of all articles, while also annotating each row with a new recommended column, which is 1 if the user in question has recommended the article or 0 if not. There shouldn't be any duplicate `Article` in the result, and I need it ordered by the `Recommendation`'s `submit_time` column.

This is on Postgres - 9.1.8.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(t.title) t.title,
  t.id, t.url, 
  MAX(recommended) as recommended
FROM ( 
    SELECT submitter_article.title as title,
      submitter_article.id as id,
      submitter_article.url as url,
      1 as recommended 
    FROM submitter_article, submitter_recommendation
    WHERE submitter_recommendation.user_id=?
      AND submitter_recommendation.article_id=submitter_article.id 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT submitter_article.title as title,
      submitter_article.id as id,
      submitter_article.url as url,
      0 as recommended
    FROM submitter_article
     ) as t 

    GROUP BY t.title, t.id, t.url, recommended
```

And I'm passing a `user id` into the `?`

I've been trying to do this for a while but can't figure it out. The queries I come up with either return all `recommended` values as 0, or return duplicate Article rows (one with `recommended=0` and the other with `recommended=1`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a subquery, `CASE` will do, `DISTINCT ON` is useless if you also use `GROUP BY` and you should use explicit joins instead of implicit joins. This query should get you started:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (sa.title) sa.title, sa.id, sa.url,
                              (CASE
                                   WHEN sr.id IS NULL THEN 0
                                   ELSE 1
                               END) AS recommended
FROM submitter_article AS sa
LEFT JOIN submitter_recommendation AS sr ON sa.id=sr.article_id
AND sr.user_id=?
ORDER BY sa.title,sr.submit_time DESC;
```

But there are still some things I'm not sure. You can have two articles with the same title but diffrent id? In that case you can select that which has earlier/later recommendation submit_time but what if there are no recommendations? You need logic for how to select distinct rows and for how to order things in the end.